# How to make git commit only tracked files

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control

I've just started to use git and It's driving me nuts. If I'm understanding the way git works correctly:

1. Even if a file is tracked you have to add it to the staging pool
   before committing it.
2. Only files in the staging pool will be committed to the local repository.
3. When a non tracked file is added to the staging pool with 'git add' it automatically becomes a tracked file.
4. When a tracked file is deleted with 'git rm' (or 'git rm --cached' if I don't want it to be deleted from the FS) a delete 'action' is inserted into the staging pool that will be implemented in the local repository on the next 'git commit'.

However, if I have a 100 tracked files that have been modified adding them all individually in preparation for a commit is pretty tedious. When I do a *svn commit* from the root of my tree subversion will by default **commit only tracked files that have been modified added with 'svn add' or deleted with 'svn rm'**.

So the question is, is there a single git command that will do what 'svn commit' does, i.e. add and commit only all the **tracked** files that have been modified or deleted and not add every single solitary file in the tree to the staging pool?

Comment: For what it's worth, it's better (because it's completely accurate) to think of the index / staging-area as "what to put in the next commit".  When you `git add` or `git rm`, you're updating the index, which continues to be "what to put in the next commit".  If you haven't updated it since a checkout, it's still full of "what to put in the next commit", it's just that everything in it is the same as everything you just checked out.

Answer (score 9):

`git add -u` should add only modified and removed files.

Comment: And just to make things a little less confusing: in Git 1.x `git add -u` adds modified and removed tracked files in the local directory and it's subdirectories. In Git 2.x **the same command** `git add -u` adds modified and removed tracked files in the **entire tree** no matter where you are in the tree while the command `git add -u .` adds all modified and removed tracked files in the directory you are in and all of its subdirectories.